# How safe is using api keys in a script in Unity WEBGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm developing a project using WEBGL and I was wondering if it is safe to use a private key directly in the code.

Let's say that I have a private key called DB_KEYS.
I must use this private key in the source code.
When I deploy the game, are the users able to see the source code of my game and so the DB_KEYS variable?

Thank you in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: Yes if you use your key in source code in variable then it is not safe. you need some server side logic to get key

Comment: Unless normal .Net builds, WebGL is actually quite unlikely to get de-compiled. I would claim until proven different a user can not simply access your code/keys ... however it depends of course a lot what exactly you do with it since if you send it undecrypted over the network then of course users could intercept those packages and extract the key from there ;)

Comment: There's no server logic. I have no server because I'm working on a decentralised game. So...if you said that it is unlikely to be de-compiled I can freely let my key in the source code, am I right?